# Поясните, как работает этот php код?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, классы, php, объекты, rest

```
Route::get('user/{id}/{name}', function ($id, $name) {

})
->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+', 'name' => '[a-z]+'));
```

Как я понимаю: объявлен класс Route, у которого есть метод get, которому в свою очередь передаётся два параметра, первый — строка, второй — анонимная функция, которую метод get может вызвать, а может и нет.

Но что такое where? чей это метод? Это get возвращает объект? Тогда что это за объект, сам Route? И как тогда можно самого себя вот так вернуть?
Судя по логике, он должен вызываться раньше анонимной функции (второй параметр).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Но что такое where? чей это метод? Это get возвращает объект?

можно просто заглянуть в исходники

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L143
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L853
http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_get

да, возвращается Route, но это уже объект другого класса

> как тогда можно самого себя вот так вернуть?

```
static function get()
{
    return new static;
}
```

Так как возвращается объект, то передаваться он будет по ссылке и все изменения объекта будут видны из всех точек доступа к объекту. Поэтому вызов ->where(), который как-либо изменит состояние объекта, может быть в итоге проанализирвоан и каким-то third-party компонентом, в то же время никто не запрещает самому Route содержать какие-то ссылки на внешние компоненты, чтобы зарегистрировать изменения там.

> которую метод get может вызвать, а может и нет.

метод get ее никогда не вызывает, он ее *регистрирует*

Comment: >>он ее регистрирует
речь идёт про случай в исходнике, или это правило языка?

Comment: @hcuser $callable, переданный аргументом, сам по себе никогда не вызовется.